# NGINX: alias or proxy based on query string

Tags: nginx

I'm looking for a way to allow a `proxy_pass` when certain querystrings are in the url and send the URI to an alias the rest of the time.

Here's how I have the in one environment, the location block is configured like this:

```
location /my-route {

    alias /assets/coming-soon/;
    index index.html;

}
```

In another, it's configured like this:

```
location /my-route {

    proxy_pass         http://tool_servers/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

}
```

I want to combine the two and pass the bare uri to to the `coming-soon` page, but URIs with `?filter=test` to `tool_servers`.

Proxy config cannot go inside an `if ($arg_filter = "test")` block (I tried). Is there another work-around?

Comment: How about `if ($arg_filter != "test") { rewrite ^ /assets/coming-soon/ last; }` or similar?

Comment: @RichardSmith That does the trick, thanks!